# How to get total sum using Index Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

There Is Sheet Containing Airlines Data As shown in the pic below[image]

Now in Sheet Q6, In Cell C16, I need to find the total distance covers using index function.
I need to Find The total distance covered with given criteria
Criteria are -
Carrier - US.
Date - 17th January 2014.
Origin - New York.
Destination City - Washington.

[image]

I have made the formula as [=SUM(INDEX('Airlines Data'!I2:I910,MATCH(1,('Q6'!C4='Airlines Data'!B2:B910)*('Q6'!E4='Airlines Data'!A2:A910)*('Q6'!C6='Airlines Data'!D2:D910)*('Q6'!E6='Airlines Data'!G2:G910),0)))]

I am not getting accurate answer. Please help.
Answer is 428.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Excel 2010 does not exist for Mac.

Comment: I am using Excel 2019

Comment: Shouldn't there be added `*` between the different equations? And is the formula entered as an array formula?

Answer (score 0):

Don't fixate on Index. It will not do what you need, so asking how to do what you need using Index is not the best way to ask.

Consider using Sumifs(), which can take several conditions.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Comment: but in this I have to get the total using index function in the cell C16  as shown in the pic